# Errors When Running Titanium-Connection-Test

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Video documentation on the Appcelerator website explains that if I'm running into errors during the titanium-connection-test that we should ask for support.

## Currently I am getting two errors:

- Testing logging in against api.appcelerator.net using cURL

  - Failed: Unexpected end of input
- Testing logging in against dashboard.appcelerator.com using cURL

  - Failed: Unexpected end of input

All other tests passed green. Any idea how I can fix these issues?

*Video Source: http://videos.appcelerator.com/video/XmWEDgSP/Installing-Appcelerator-Studio/bSvBEOmi/Get-Started*

Comment: Well despite the errors, I still have access to my projects on my Appcelerator Dashboard and can run the application on the titanium emulator with no errors.

Comment: tried clearing cookies & other browser? Anyways, this is not an Stackoverflow question. This is a support question

Comment: I'd love to reach out and ask them but they have disabled their support on their site in favor of Stack Overflow. "Attention: In January 2016 we embraced Stack Overflow for Appcelerator Community Support. This read-only archive of the original (2010 - 2014) and former (2015) Q&A's contains a lot of out-dated information so use with care. Also see our new Developer Portal for more ways to get help."

Source: https://archive.appcelerator.com/

Comment: there is support if you're logged in. The red bubble on the bottom right. Ask them